# How to dynamically adjust margins using java script in ASP .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this **div id=popupContent** which shows some data in popup window

**related css class**

```
.popupWindow 
{ 
  position:absolute; 
  top:10%;
  left:30%;
  z-index:1001;
  background-color:#fff;
 }
```

In some cases content of this div has to stretch to width of 1000px. So on lower resolutions it shows only part of popup window.
I want to dynamically adjust this top and left attributes based on screen resolution.

So for example if resolution is 1920x1080 **top** should be 10% ; **left** 30% , 
on 1280x760 **top:**  5% **left:** 10%....

If anyone knows solution, I'll be thankful.

Comment: Try CSS Media Query. You may check here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Just giving another option as you tagged javaScript in your question. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bjx09uxj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px), screen and (max-height:1080px) {
  .popupWindow 
      {
        top:10%;
        left:30%;
      }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px), screen and (max-height:760px) {
  .popupWindow 
      {
        top:5%;
        left:10%;
      }
}
```